# Looping JSON from Parse database giving wrong results

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, dictionary

> Swift 2.0, xcode 7.1

I am trying to retrieve some data from Parse database, filter it to remove duplicate and store in a dictionary. Each row of parse has orders placed by customer (JSON shown below) and I want to retrieve this in UITableView to show the order placed. If the customer has placed multiple orders recently, I want to filter that and show all of his orders in one section of table view under his customer ID.

Filtering is working, but for some reason my loop is not giving me accurate results.

Parse Row 1:

> [{"Customer":"9sKSDTG7GY","Product":"Burger","Quantity":"2"}]

Parse Row 2:

> [{"Customer":"nyRHskbTwG","Product":"Sizzler","Quantity":"2"},{"Customer":"nyRHskbTwG","Product":"Biryani","Quantity":"2"}]

Retrieved this data and stored in self.custome, self.fQuantity and self.fName variable.

The loop I am using is as below:

```
let cD = self.customer
                print("Customer data before filtering Unique value: \(self.customer)")
                self.uniqueValues = self.uniq(cD) //Calling a function to get unique values in customer data

  print("Customer data after filtering Unique value: \(self.uniqueValues)")
            var newArray = [[String]]()

            for var count = 0; count < self.customer.count; count++ {
                for sID in self.uniqueValues {
                    if sID.containsString(self.customer[count]){

                        let dicValue = [String(self.fQuantity[count]), String(self.fName[count])]
                        newArray.append(dicValue)

                        self.dicArray.updateValue(newArray, forKey: sID)
                    } else {
                        // Do nothing...
                    }
                }
            }

            print("Dictionary Values: \(Array(self.dicArray.values))")
            print("Dictionary Keys: \(Array(self.dicArray.keys))")
```

Printed output is as below:

> Customer data before filtering Unique value: ["9sKSDTG7GY",
>   "nyRHskbTwG", "nyRHskbTwG"]
>
> Customer data after filtering Unique value: ["9sKSDTG7GY",
>   "nyRHskbTwG"]
>
> Dictionary Values: [[["2", "Burger"], ["2", "Sizzler"],
>   ["2", "Biryani"]], [["2", "Burger"]]]
>
> Dictionary Keys: ["nyRHskbTwG", "9sKSDTG7GY"]

Can someone figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David suggested, you have to swap outer and inner loop. But I also had to delete all values contained in newArray if there was nothing found in the if loop. So this is how I made it work.

```
let cD = self.customer
                print("Customer data before filtering Unique value: \(self.customer)")
                self.uniqueValues = self.uniq(cD) //Calling a function to get unique values in customer data

  print("Customer data after filtering Unique value: \(self.uniqueValues)")
        var newArray = [[String]]()

        for sID in self.uniqueValues {
 for var count = 0; count < self.customer.count; count++ {
                if sID.containsString(self.customer[count]){

                    let dicValue = [String(self.fQuantity[count]), String(self.fName[count])]
                    newArray.append(dicValue)

                    self.dicArray.updateValue(newArray, forKey: sID)
                } else {
                   newArray.removeAll() // ****** Adding this works for me

                }
            }
        }

        print("Dictionary Values: \(Array(self.dicArray.values))")
        print("Dictionary Keys: \(Array(self.dicArray.keys))")
```

Answer (score 1):

You filtered the data, but are looping through the un-filtered list of customers.

```
    for var count = 0; count < self.customer.count; count++ {
```

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear or I am using wrong model. But to get all the order placed, I have to loop through the unfiltered list. As you can see I have two orders in Row 2 by same Customer. So I am using the filtered array to loop through the unfiltered key's to get there values. I may not be clear in my explanation. But can you please have a second look?

Comment: In that case, perhaps you want to be reverse the order of your loops: the outer loop would loop through the unique customer id's, the inner loop collects all orders for that id.

Comment: I just tried that. Getting the same result even after reversal? Is this the right way to loop? I looked at it and it should work, but not sure why I am getting the values wrong. Order from Row 2 is somehow attached to Row 1 customer. Strange.